# Iptables allow DNS resolution

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, iptables

i made this script for IPTABLES without state.
I need to block any output connection except SSH, DNS, ICMP and Ubuntu Repositories

```
#! /bin/bash
#Objetivo del script:
#Descartar paquetes  excepto ssh y DNS
#FIREWALL DE HOST SIN ESTADO Servidor
#Cleanup Rules
iptables -t filter -P INPUT DROP
iptables -t filter -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -t filter -P FORWARD DROP
#allow loopback
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
#DNS resolution input and output
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -d 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -s 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4 -j ACCEPT
#updates since ubuntu repositories
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d archive.ubuntu.com,security.ubuntu.com -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s archive.ubuntu.com,security.ubuntu.com -m multiport --sports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
#allow ssh
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT

#allow ICMP
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
```

The result is this:

```
iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables): host/network `archive.ubuntu.com' not found
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables): host/network `archive.ubuntu.com' not found
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

Comment: You should probably not attempt to whitelist mirrors in this way. IP's are prone to change, and they may have a large number of mirrors.

Comment: DNS uses UDP **AND** TCP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance you're only allowing DNS responses to be received and don't create any DNS related rules in the OUTPUT chain to actually allow sending DNS queries out.

You current rules:

```
#DNS resolution input and output
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -d 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4 -j ACCEPT
            ^^^^^
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -s 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4 -j ACCEPT
            ^^^^^
```

Additionally, DNS can also use TCP for transport.

Comment: It Works! Thnk you!

Answer (score 0):

The issues seems to be from DNS resolution.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -d 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4 -j ACCEPT
```

It allows 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 hosts to reach to your server on destination port 53. If you have any DNS service running on your station/server.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -s 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4 -j ACCEPT
```

And above rule says, allow 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 hosts to access your station/server if their source-port is 53.

I would go for a general rule like below, to allow all DNS queries from your station to any DNS server.
Its also recommended to open TCP as well, since TCP must be used to exchange information larger than 512 bytes.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```